# Deploying models in the real world

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning

I've been thinking about this for a while. **I really would like to know other opinions so please answer, even if it sounds stupid!**

Just as any application, ML/DL models can be deployed in a very wide range of ways. I've tried many architectures, but have no definitive answer or straightforward solution for which one to choose.

I'll be focusing on real-time online models, which are usually the solutions I need.

The first solution being obviously a flask server, provides a quick way of deploying, but not very suitable for production.

After that, I changed it to a gRPC server, which adds streaming and higher throughput, but still no resilience or way of ensuring messages were delivered. That'd have to be a custom solution on the client side.

Then I started looking at Spark with pandas udfs. In case you don't know what a pandas udf is, basically the code is wrapped into a function that will be run agains batches of data. The problem here is that the models must be loaded on each batch. In some cases this could be solved by broadcasting the model (a way of sharing a variable between nodes in the cluster) but this is not always an option. This introduces a performance tradeoff where you must choose a big enaugh batch in order for the model not to be loaded all the time, but also the larger the batch, the bigger the latency.

Tensorflow serving is stupid. When I tried it, the serialization took more time than the actual inference. This was because the first layer of the model received an image and I had to send an array of pixels for each image. In order to fix this serialization step, I added a base64 decoding layer and sent it that way. Additionally, it has no inference guarantees, and the last time I used it the model couldn't contain custom layers unless you implement the counterpart in C++. Also, no support for lambda layers. This makes most of the models online unusable.

I'm really curious if I'm overthinking this, or everyone is having this problem. **Please share your experience**. Thank you

PS: I also started this discussion on [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/deeplearning/comments/riht0n/deploying_models_in_the_real_world/) in case you wanted to join.

Comment: We deploy all of ours through Django Rest Framework -- simple, use any auth method you want, has rate limiting, put diskcache (fast/huge/cheap in cloud) between the request and TF/Torch, use Celery (w/ JS in front end to wait for result to fill cache) for long stuff to take out of line.  Torch is fast enough for reasonable real time look ahead for us.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have/need any retry logic? Is scaling up and down a concern? Or the requests just have a uniform distribution?